# Wicket file upload with preview

Tags: ajax, file-upload, wicket, nested-forms, preview

I am using wicket 1.7 and I would like to implement a file uploading cmponent (upload an image) with preview. I searched and read severals solutions into the Web but I do not understand well how to do it.

Is it mandatory to submit the form to obtain the preview ? And is it possible to submit only the file upload form and not the entire form ?

Is it possible to submit the form without adding a preview button and add simply an Ajax behavior on file upload ?

Thanks for any help.
I am pretty new into the wicket world.

Comment: You can submit only upload form it's possible. Try drop behaviour on your case will definitely works

Comment: Thanks, I think to do like you propose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For file preview you don't need to upload the file to the server. This could be done with JavaScript.

Wicket-Bootstrap provides integration with JavaScript widget that provides this functionality:

demo: http://coding.teliclab.info/wicket-7.x/extensions/BootstrapFileInput

JS widget: https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput

Wicket code: https://github.com/l0rdn1kk0n/wicket-bootstrap/tree/wicket-7.x/bootstrap-extensions/src/main/java/de/agilecoders/wicket/extensions/markup/html/bootstrap/form/fileinput

Wicket example code: https://github.com/l0rdn1kk0n/wicket-bootstrap/blob/wicket-7.x/bootstrap-samples/src/main/java/de/agilecoders/wicket/samples/pages/ExtensionsBootstrapFileInputPage.java

Comment: Thanks Martin, we can speek even in bulgarian :) The demo is nice but the problem is that we use an old wicket version. Do you know if it is compatible with wicket 1.7 ? Finally I thing I will add a submit button just for the image form, so I will check the mime type, the size and also a resize will be done and the image will be show into a div preview with some Ajax behavior. But your response seems to be powerful solution, so it is well to know it.

Comment: Здравей! There is no version 1.7. The last one from 1.x series is 1.5.x. Then we jumped to 6.x, 7.x and soon 8.x.

Comment: Благодаря, I will check that, but I am sure that we use one of the oldest versions even before 6, so probably 1.5.

Comment: Congrats for 10k

Comment: Thanks, @soorapadman! With all the help you provide for 'wicket' tags lately you will reach me soon! :-)